# CSS: How To Fix HTML Child Elements Not Respecting Parent 100vh

Tags: html, css, flexbox, viewport

**The GIF below is the layout that I want to achieve with HTML and CSS.**

[image]

The code below also represents the layout above. However if you fill in the child elements with content and **resize the browser window**, the children do not respect the body's view-port height of `100vh`. The content overlaps each other and some of the children push down their siblings hence the parent's `viewport` of `100vh` is not respected.

CODE BELOW:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 50px;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

#section-1_alert-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#section-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#alert {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  max-height: 30%;
  height: 50%;
}

#section-2 {
  background-color: rgb(24, 255, 243);
  ;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="header">header</header>

  <main id="main">

    <div id="section-1_alert-wrapper">

      <div id="section-1">Section 1
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste? Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
        esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem
        expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi,
        vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?
      </div>

      <div id="alert">Alert
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
        esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem
        expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="section-2">Section 2
      <br>
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
      esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem
      expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?
    </div>

  </main>

  <footer id="footer">footer</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

What I want to achieve if for the **alert**, **section 1**, and **section 2** to become scroll-able once content fills up their entire space and still adhere to the body's `100vh` even on browser window resize. The alert's max-height should be `30%` once content fills up it's space. The `body` should also **NEVER become scroll-able** even on window resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an `overflow-y` property with a value `auto` to the classes you want scroll-able. `auto` ensures that a scrollbar is added to an element only when its content has exceeded its height

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#header {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  height: 10vh;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 80vh;
}

#section-1_alert-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#section-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#alert {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  max-height: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#section-2 {
  background-color: rgb(24, 255, 243);
  ;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header id="header">header</header>

  <main id="main">

    <div id="section-1_alert-wrapper">

      <div id="section-1">Section 1
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste? Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
        esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem
        expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi,
        vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?
      </div>

      <div id="alert">Alert
        <br>
        <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
        esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem
        expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="section-2">Section 2
      <br>
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
      esse, quas exercitationem expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et esse, quas exercitationem
      expedita ipsum animi, vitae dolor voluptates culpa saepe quibusdam quis obcaecati eos assumenda molestias laudantium cupiditate quod iste?
    </div>

  </main>

  <footer id="footer">footer</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now content overflow is resolved. But is the main browser window still has a scrollbar. I want to main window to be 100vh (no scrollbar). only section 1, section 2 and alert should be scrollable

Comment: I just edited the code above. I changed the height of the `header`, `main` and `footer` to `10vh`, `80vh` and `10vh` respectively. Also, an `overflow-y` property was added to the body with a value of `hidden` in order to remove the scrollbar entirely from it